# what does/this meaning ->>> function deletedata(str){ }

Tags: jquery

i need some explanation for this, for what this line is doing and how to use for updating/deleting data in database with use of Ajax. thanks

```
function deletedata(str){

var id = str;

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "url.php?id="+id
}).done(function( data ) {
  $('#result').html(data);
  search();
});
}
```

Comment: didnt get the question

Comment: what i want to know is how to use and for what this line for [ function delete(str){} ]

Comment: function delete(str){
    code goes here
    }

Comment: as far as I know, it's a  js function that does nothing, you're specifying that it's a function with the 'function' word, giving it a name 'delete' that takes 1 parameter 'variable'

Comment: sorry for not completing my question, how about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it calls a php page in the same directory called

> url.php

url.php takes 1 Argument - which is the 'id'.

It must have inside it something like

```
<?php echo mysql_query("delete from TABLENAME where id == $_GET['id']");?>
```

Keep in mind to use 'htmlspecialchar' on the ID to not get sql-injected.